# How to restrict object types which can be added in user personal folders in Plone 4.1?

Tags: plone

Have Plone 4.1 with Ploneboard installed and using the intranet_workflow. I don't want users to be able to create Ploneboard objects in their user folders. If I enable user folders and set restrictions on the users folder to standard Plone types, then Ploneboard objects do not appear in the add menu for users in their own home folder. But Restrictions still appears, and users can click on that and edit the restrictions to allow themselves to add Ploneboard objects. How can I remove the ability for users to alter the restrictions set on their personal folders?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Plone products define custom *add permissions* to allow fine-grain tuning for where and by who they can be added.

Ploneboard's main *add permission* is *Ploneboard: Add Ploneboard* and it's set for *Manager* and *Owner* roles by default. Because the members are owners of their member folders, they get the permission to add boards.

The easiest way to change this is (after the Ploneboard has already been installed) is to

1. go to the very root of Zope
2. open the ZMI (*/manage*)
3. select the *Security*-tab
4. search for the permission named *Ploneboard: Add Ploneboard*
5. unselect *Owner*-role to not have that permission
6. go to the end of the page and *Save changes*

Now, only the users with *Manager* role have permission to add boards.

If you are on Plone 4.1 (or newer) and would like to give that permission also to the users with the new *Site Administrator* role, you should open the *Security*-tab for the Plone site object, search the permission and set it there.